# Using sed within a vi buffer

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, sed

In a long text file listing dups-23Mar16.listing I want to delete lines
beginning, for example, with `.local`. Here are some lines in this file:

```
Desktop/Reisen/Italien/VillaLaBandita/images-hpz-urlaub/cimg0429.jpg
Desktop/Tiere/Italien/VillaLaBandita/images-hpz-urlaub/cimg0429.jpg
.local/share/files/eksteuer/ekst.odt
```

From outside of this file I can do this with the command

```
sed  -e '/^\.[a-z]/d' dups-23Mar16.listing
```

and in a vi buffer by

```
:%!sed  -e '/^\.[a-z]/d'
```

If I want to remove the lines beginning with Desktop as well I succeed with

```
:%!sed  -e '/^Desktop/d'
```

How can I combine both commands into one? 
I tried

```
:%!(sed  -e '/^\.[a-z]/d';sed -e '/^Desktop/d')
```

but this does not work. What is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

If you really want that, you can simply give multiple **-e** parameters to **sed** like this:

```
:%!sed -e '/^\.[a-z]/d' -e '/^Desktop/d'
```

I just don't know if you want this just for some experience in **sed** or you are not aware that inside **vim**, there is **ed** that knows everything **sed** does and more... and without starting an unnecessary process:

```
g/^\(\.[a-z]\|Desktop\)/d
```

Comment: I simply did'nt know better.  Helpful for both: experience in sed and the learning power of ed. Each version does what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this at the vi buffer command line, this should work--without sed:

```
:exe 'g/^Desktop/d'|g/^\.[a-z]/d
```

The vertical bar separates multiple commands on a vi command line.  The `g` works to process the entire buffer, as the Regular expressions should qualify the delete commands to work with every line that matches.  The `exe` and quotes are needed to prevent a global recursion error.

Comment: You  wrote "The g works to process the entire buffer", but there is no g in your command, where do I have to place it. As it stands the command did not properly. I would be grateful seeing a corrected version.

Comment: My bad.  I made a couple of edits and managed to drop that correction on the floor.  Fixed now.  Hope this helps!